# Hibernate criteria question

Tags: java, hibernate

I have following POJO`s:
- Company

- Node
  (nodeID, company)
- User
  (userID, node)

I want to create where clause(via Criteria) which will return to me every user for given company. Something like ...

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class)
criteria.add(Restrinctions.eq("node.company", someCompanyObject);
```

But this is not working, so is it possible to do this with criteria class or should use
HQL/SQL?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations) says:

> By navigating associations using createCriteria() you can specify constraints upon related entities:
>
> ```
> List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
>     .add( Restrictions.like("name", "F%") )
>     .createCriteria("kittens")
>         .add( Restrictions.like("name", "F%") )
>     .list();
> ```

Transposed to your problem:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class) 
    .createCriteria( "node" )
    .add( Restrinctions.eq( "company", someCompanyObject) );
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping and excuse me for errors, but i write example code manually. I think that this way is the better solution for me!

Answer (score 2):

You use the id...

```
Restrinctions.eq("node.company.id", someCompanyObject.id);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is possible with Criteria API. Your code has some errors, but perhaps they are just typos. It is hard to tell what the error is without looking at the table and the hibernate configuration. Try something like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
List users = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("node.company", someCompanyObject))
            .list();
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want save some code use Seimos at http://github.com/moesio/seimos

As an example, you can use criteria as follows:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Cat.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.like(“description”, “Pap”)
  .addOrder(Order.asc(“description”);

Criteria subCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("kind", "kind");
subCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("description", "persa"));

Criteria anotherSubCriteria = subCriteria.createCriteria("anAssociation","anAssociation");
anotherSubCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("attribute", "anything"));

criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Cat.class));

criteria.crateAlias(“kind.anAssociation”, “kind_anAssociation”);

criteria.setProjections(Projections.projectionList()
  .add(Projections.alias(Projections.property(“id”), “id”))
  .add(Projections.alias(Projections.property(“kind.id”, “kind.id”))
  .add(Projections.alias(Projections.property(“kind.anAssocation.attribute”, “kind.anAssociation.attribute”))

List cats = criteria.list();
```

But if you want save some code, you can use Seimos and code just

```
Filters filters = new Filters();
filters.add(new Filters(“description”, “Pap”)
  .add(new Filter(“description”))
  .add(new Filter("kind.description", "persa"))
  .add(new Filter("kind.anAssociation.attribute", "anything"));
List<Cat> cats = dao.find(filters);
```

So, consider use http://github.com/moesio/seimos